# Downloading Work shared model from BIM 360 Design

Tags: autodesk-forge

Using Forge API, is it possible to download a Work-shared Revit Model from BIM 360 Design to local machine and i need to open it and again sync it.The below code is used for downloading a file, but not possible to Sync to central. The connection to BIM 360 Design is not maintained in the Model.

```
        ObjectsApi itemApi = new ObjectsApi();          
        string BucketKey = "wip.dm.prod";
        string objectName = "1a79a3a0-888f-4dec-8c82-96de7f07d19b.rvt";          
        itemApi.Configuration.AccessToken=await Get2LeggedTokenAsync(new Scope[] { Scope.DataCreate, Scope.DataWrite, Scope.AccountRead, Scope.ViewablesRead, Scope.DataRead });
            dynamic content=   itemApi.GetObject(BucketKey, objectName);
```

can you please help me to solve this scenario.

Thanks

Bimal George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 legged Account Admin token or 3 legged token to download the cloud worksharing model after it's published to BIM360 Docs, but I don't suggest you access it directly from Bucket, instead, please follow the link https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/documen-management/download-document/ to get it from Hub->Project->Folder->Item-Version, that's the suggested way, and you can also upload a new version with the similar way.

I answered another related question in Revit forum at https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/is-it-possible-to-open-a-bim-360-model-without-using-forge/m-p/8297315, it's talking about how to get the model and open it in Revit, you can check.

Comment: But the downloaded file is not work shared, is there possibility to download the file itself as work shared

Comment: Unfortunately, we can only download the model after it's published to BIM360 Docs, we can not download the work shared model if it's not published.